# Download PDF Using PDFShift in Laravel

Tags: laravel, pdf-generation

I use Laravel and have implemented all the things according to the documentation. After that, I was able to save the PDF into the project directory. However, I want to download the PDF to the user's computer when someone clicks the download link. How can I do this?

The method that I used.

```php
PDFShift::setApiKey('120d8e8a86d2....................');
PDFShift::convertTo('https://www.example.com', null, 'result.pdf');
```

PdfShift GitHub repo - https://github.com/pdfshift/pdfshift-php

Comment: I suppose you'd want to create a download response using the generated file.  Have you tried this https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#file-downloads ?